# What is triggering the component to re-render

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-redux

So, before i had some code in my reducer that looked like this, and my component was not re-rendering even though lists was mapped to the React props correctly (via mapStateToProps):

```
case "ADDTOLIST":
    let stateCopy = Object.assign({}, state);

    let listsCopy = stateCopy.lists;
    listsCopy.push(action.item);

    return {...state, lists: listsCopy};
```

Then I just changed the line where I set listsCopy to this - so I used slice to create a copy of the lists array:

```
let listsCopy = stateCopy.lists.slice();
```

And now my component re-renders correctly!  So my question is why is the call to slice triggering a re-render of the component?  Versus before where i was just assigning it normally.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here/ what I'm not understanding?  A console log in the "before" code seemed to show that "listsCopy" was being modified as expected, but did not trigger a state change.

Also, I am using a copy of the state and not mutating it.  I'm just not sure why the slice makes a difference here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating the array. With redux, you must *always* return a new copy of anything you modify.

```
return {...state, lists: [...state.lists, action.item]};
```

The reason slice works and not push, is because .slice returns a new copy of the array. Push mutates.

Also, the way Object.assign works... it creates a new root object, however it does not work recursively. Something to research for you: The difference between value and reference types. Value types are things like a string, number, boolean, null or undefined. Each of these things are a raw value and can be compared directly. However, reference types are like objects or arrays or any instance of a custom class or function. In essence, they cannot be compared directly, even if they have the same contents.

For example:

```
var foo = ['foo']
var bar = ['foo']
// foo === bar : false

var a = Object.assign({}, {foo: foo})
// a.foo === foo : true

var b = Object.assign({}, {foo: foo}, {foo: bar})
// b.foo === bar : true
// b.foo === foo : false
```

Basic rule is any time you have a nested object  (such as array or object) inside of your main reducer - if you make changes to that, you must return a new copy.

What is happening with redux is exactly what you see inside of `var a`. Even though you updated the contents of the array, redux is just doing a strict equality check for each root key of the reducer to determine if it should update components. So when you return the pushed array, it sees that object as identical to the previous state - because it is the same instance of the array in both cases. Redux does not consider what's inside the array (or object).

Comment: To add onto this, this is why using a library like immutable.js works really well with redux. From my personal experience, there's typically been more benefits from using it compared to any overhead (ie boilerplate)